# Flink : how to set task manager properties through flink code

Tags: apache-flink

i am getting error "Caused by: java.io.IOException: Insufficient number of network buffers: required 30, but only 25 available. The total number of network buffers is currently set to 12945 of 32768 bytes each. You can increase this number by setting the configuration keys 'taskmanager.network.memory.fraction', 'taskmanager.network.memory.min', and 'taskmanager.network.memory.max'."

I am running this flink code from eclipse.
I know how to set task manager properties from flink-conf.yaml
but how can i set if i am running through IDE.

Answer (score 0):

When executing `DataSet` jobs you need to call `ExecutionEnvironment.createLocalEnvironment(Configuration configuration)` in order to pass in a custom `Configuration`.

When executing `DataStream` jobs you need to call `StreamExecutionEnvironment.createLocalEnvironment(int parallelism, Configuration configuration)` in order to pass in a custom `Configuration`.